# Q&A Sites for machine learning and NLP

Tags: machine-learning

So my question is asking for recommending good Q&A sites about machine learning, NLP or data mining. I think guys here may often go to these relevant sites.

Comment: Voting to close.  This question is off-topic since it isn't a question about data analysis.  Read the faq: http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: Machine learning and data mining are entirely within the scope of this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MetaOptimize](http://metaoptimize.com/qa/) is great.

I also like [Reddit/Machine Learning](http://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/) (it's not really a Q&A site, though, so you don't really get too many technical questions.).

Answer (score 0):

[Quora](http://www.quora.com/) might be one option.